# Slicing the word to rows -TERADATA

Tags: database, teradata

I want to slice a word eg: SMILE into :

```
S
M
I
L
E
```

I did it like this

```
SEL SUBSTR(EMP_NAME,1,1) FROM etlt5.employe  where  EMP_ID='28008' 
 UNION ALL
 SEL SUBSTR(EMP_NAME,2,1) FROM etlt5.employe  where  EMP_ID='28008' 
 UNION ALL
 SEL SUBSTR(EMP_NAME,3,1) FROM etlt5.employe  where  EMP_ID='28008'
```

I also tried it with recursive query but no final results.is there a better way of doing this because this looks more like a hardcoded one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` to do this. `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE` splits a field by a delimiter and then takes each token (stuff between the delimiter) and sticks it in it's own record of a new derived table.

In your case you don't have a delimiter between the characters of "SMILE" so we can use some `REGEXP_REPLACE` magic to stick a comma between each letter, and then split that to a table:

```
WITH test (id, word) AS (SELECT 1, 'SMILE')
SELECT D.*
FROM TABLE (strtok_split_to_table(test.id, REGEXP_REPLACE(test.word, '([a-zA-Z])', ',\1'), ',')
RETURNS
( id integer
, rownum integer
, new_col varchar(100)character set unicode)
) as d
```

I've used this `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE(REGEXP_REPLACE())` before to split apart document numbers in order to determine a check digit, so it definitely has its uses.

Answer (score 0):

May I ask *why*  you want to do that?

You need a table with a sequence from 1 to the max length of EMP_NAME:

```
select SUBSTR(EMP_NAME,n,1) 
FROM etlt5.employe CROSS JOIN number_table
where  EMP_ID='28008'
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @dnoeth :)